Why not-found.tsx doesn't work on specific route?
I created not-found.tsx for the /blogs/[id] route, but for some reason it does not work exactly on that route. For the rest application global not-found.tsx works properly. Maybe it is because /blogs/[id] has a parallel route and there is something wrong with default.tsx ?

There error screenshot:

Code from layout.tsx:
import { fetchBlogById } from '@/app/lib/data';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';

interface Props {
  params: { id: string };
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { id } }: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const blog = await fetchBlogById(id);

  if (!blog) notFound();

  return {
    title: {
      template: `%s | ${blog.title}`,
      default: blog.title,
    },
  };
}

export default function Layout({
  children,
  modal,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  modal: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      {modal}
    </div>
  );
}

How can I fix this bug?

this is an open issue for dynamic routes, looks like there was an attempt at fixing it a few months back but commenters say its not fully fixed, you could try upgrading and see if your scenario is resolved, also try 'use-client' and see if it works better client side, otherwise you'll need to manually handle 404s from dynamic routes. main discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/57938
